# SSLSocketFactory is null when using HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java

I get the following exception when I run the following piece of code:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.

Code:

```
String https_url = "https://www.google.com/";
URL url;
url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.getResponseCode();
```

This code runs properly on different machines than mine, I think its related to the proxy that is preventing the connection.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Add `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");` and see what errors you get.

Comment: I recieved the following:setting up default SSLSocketFactory
class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory is loaded
IBMJSSE2 will not allow protocol SSLv3 per com.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3 set to TRUE or default
IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20151222
instantiated an instance of class com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.

Comment: I managed to set this value to true yet I recieved this:

setting up default SSLSocketFactory
IBMJSSE2 will allow protocol SSLv3 per com.ibm.jsse2.disableSSLv3 set to FALSE
IBMJSSEProvider2 Build-Level: -20151222
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLSocketFactory is null. This can occur if javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault() is called to create a socket and javax.net.ssl.* properties are not set.

Comment: Might this be helpful... https://coderanch.com/t/573425/java/javax-net-ssl-SSLException-SSLSocketFactory